# How to find out about loaded d3.js extensions and their versions at runtime?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

As is customary with JavaScript libraries, the global root object supplied by [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) has a self-identification attribute that returns (and thus, outputs, when called in the console) the version of the used library. In this case, it is

```
d3.version
```

Now, [since version 4.0, d3.js is modular](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v4.0.0) in that plenty of functionality built on top of the core features are placed in separate libraries, which have their own release cycles.

Now, I'm wondering whether I can also find out the version of, say, an extension such as [d3-selection-multi](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi) that is currently loaded in my JavaScript environment. Is there a separate root object for every such extension with a `version` field of its own, or is that information (preferrably even a list of all loaded extensions?) provided somewhere in the `d3` root object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way of detecting a module's version at runtime. D3's modules do not expose a `version` property like the bundle does nor does the bundle include any information about the included modules.